# Send email from yahoo using JavaMail

Tags: java, android

I try to send emails from yahoo using javamail

I used code but Authentication required error appear to me

```
public class YahooMail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 

  static {   
      Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());   
  }

  public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
      this._to = toArr;
      }

      public void setFrom(String string) {
      this._from = string;
      }

      public void setSubject(String string) {
      this._subject = string;
      }
  public YahooMail() { 
    _host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "587"; // default smtp port  465
    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = ""; // email subject 
    _body = ""; // email body 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);  
  } 

  public YahooMail(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      //Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      Session l_session = Session.getInstance(props,this);

      l_session.setDebug(true);

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(l_session);

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 
      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
      Properties props = new Properties(); 

      props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.debug", "false");
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  }
}
```

Log Cat :

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.1 Authentication required
```

Please how I solve this problem
and what changes to send from Hotmail after solve previous problem

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add full sacktrace please?

Comment: is yahoo's `SMTP` port is `567` or `465` ?

Comment: I try two port number but the same thing